# How to pass Ruby variables to a JavaScript function in a Rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I'm wondering what the best practice is for passing variables to JavaScript functions in a rails view.  Right now I'm doing something like:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){          
        js_function(<%= @ruby_array.to_json %>, <%= @ruby_var %>); )}
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A few options:

**escape_javascript**

Alias: `j`.

Works only on strings.

Escapes characters that can have special meanings in Javascript strings,
like backslash escapes, into a format suitable to put inside Javascript string literal quotes.

Maintains `html_safe` status of input,
so needs `html_safe` otherwise special HTML chars like `<` would get escaped into `&lt;`.

```
<% a = "\\n<" %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  '<%= j(a)           %>' === '\\n&lt;'
  '<%= j(a).html_safe %>' === '\\n<'
<% end %>
```

**to_json + html_safe**

As mentioned by Vyacheslav, go upvote him.

Works because JSON is [almost a subset of Javascript object literal notation](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Works not only on hash objects, but also on strings, arrays and integers which are
converted to JSON fragments of the corresponding data type.

```
<% data = { key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2' } %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var data = <%= data.to_json.html_safe %>
  data.key1 === 'val1'
  data.key2 === 'val2'
<% end %>
```

**data- attributes**

Add values to attributes, retrieve them with Javascript DOM operations.

Better with the `content_tag` helper:

```
<%= content_tag 'div', '', id: 'data', data: {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'} %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $('#data').data('key1') === 'val1'
  $('#data').data('key2') === 'val2'
<% end %>
```

Sometimes called "unobtrusive Javascript".

**gon**

Library specialized for the job: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Probably the most robust solution.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'gon'
```

Controller:

```
gon.key1 = 'val1'
gon.key2 = 'val2'
```

Layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <%= include_gon %>
```

View:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  gon.key1 === 'val1'
  gon.key2 === 'val2'
<% end %>
```

**See also**

- [Injecting variable values into javascript and HAML in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708369/injecting-variable-values-into-javascript-and-haml-in-ror)

Answer (score 8):

```
- content_for :javascripts_vars do
  = "var costs_data = #{@records[:cost_mode][:data].to_json}".html_safe
  = "var graph_data = #{@records[:cost_mode][:graph].to_json}".html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a technique called "unobtrusive javascript". Here's a Railscast about it: [link text](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) . It works both with prototype an jQuery. There are also plugins that can help simplify some of the tasks described in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I found that gem [client variable](https://github.com/coffa/client_variable), it helps you to do it easily.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Answer (score 0):

In HAML can data are presented so:

```
.position{data: {latitude: @claim.latitude.to_json, longitude: @claim.longitude.to_json}}

:javascript
   var latitude = $('.position').data('latitude');
   var longitude = $('.position').data('longitude');
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you aren't using `escape_javascript` in a view, you can [include it in your ruby code](http://www.myowndb.com/node/63.html) like so:

```
require 'action_view/helpers/javascript_helper'
include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper
# escape_javascript is available here.
```

or if that wont work for you, then copy the [source of the function](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L8-L34) in to your code, if need be:

```
  JS_ESCAPE_MAP = {
    '\\'    => '\\\\',
    "</"    => '<\/',
    "\r\n"  => '\n',
    "\n"    => '\n',
    "\r"    => '\n',
    '"'     => '\\"',
    "'"     => "\\'"
  }

  JS_ESCAPE_MAP["\342\200\250".dup.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8).encode!] = "&#x2028;"
  JS_ESCAPE_MAP["\342\200\251".dup.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8).encode!] = "&#x2029;"

  # Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments.
  #
  # Also available through the alias j(). This is particularly helpful in JavaScript
  # responses, like:
  #
  #   $('some_element').replaceWith('<%= j render 'some/element_template' %>');
  def escape_javascript(javascript)
    if javascript
      result = javascript.gsub(/(\\|<\/|\r\n|\342\200\250|\342\200\251|[\n\r"'])/u) { |match| JS_ESCAPE_MAP[match] }
      javascript.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result
    else
      ""
    end
  end
```