# Ruby on Rails - Send JavaScript variable from controller to external Javascript asset file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website in Ruby on Rails.  I have a controller action that renders a view like so:

```
def show
  time_left = Time.now.to_i - 3.hours.to_i
  @character = current_user.characters.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @character }
  end
end
```

This is fine as it renders the show.html.erb as I like.  I would like however to somehow pass time_left to the view as a Javascript variable as this value is use by a countdown JQuery plugin.

I could put a javascript block on the page in the HTML and print a instance variable out like so:

```
<script type="javascript"> $('#countdown').countdown('<%= @time_left =>')</script>
```

But I would like to keep all my JS in a external file and off the page could anyone give some advice on how to implement this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464966/passing-ruby-variables-to-javascript-functio‌​n-in-rails-view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Rewrite your JS code into function with one argument (timelimit) and put it into some external file. Then you can call the function from view and pass that `@timeleft` variable as JS function argument.

Short example:

```
#controller
@time_left = Time.now.to_i - 3.hours.to_i
```

.

```
#javascript
function count_down(time_left) {
  $('#countdown').countdown(time_left)
}
```

.

```
#view
<%=javascript_tag "count_down(#{@time_left})" -%>
```

[javascript_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#M001759)

Example not tested, it is only idea not complete solution. Don't forget to load that JS file. You can use other JS rails helper [javascript_include_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#M001713).

Comment: Actually today I would suggest to use meta tag attribute to pass variables into the page. You can read those attributes via javascript easily.

Answer (score 5):

retro's technique of using a function parameter is a possibility, but you have to properly escape the variable you are passing with either **escape_javascript** or **to_json + html_safe** as explained below.

However, since you want to affect external files, the best techniques will be to use **gon**. Another good possibility is to use **data- attributes**.

**gon**

Gem specialized for the job: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Probably the most robust solution.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'gon'
```

Controller:

```
gon.timeleft = 1
```

Layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <%= include_gon %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Asset file:

```
gon.timeleft === 1
```

**data- attributes**

Add values to attributes, retrieve them with JavaScript DOM operations.

Sometimes called "unobtrusive Javascript".

View head:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

View body:

```
<%= content_tag 'div', '', id: 'data', data: {timeleft: '1'} %>
```

Asset file:

```
$(function() {
  parseInt($('#data').data('key1')) === 1
})
```

---

The following illustrate how `escape_javascript` and `to_json` work for you to use on top of retro's answer.

**escape_javascript**

Alias: `j`.

Works only on strings.

Escapes characters that can have special meanings in JavaScript strings,
like backslash escapes, into a format suitable to put inside JavaScript string literal quotes.

Maintains `html_safe` status of input,
so needs `html_safe` otherwise special HTML chars like `<` would get escaped into `&lt;`.

```
<% a = "\\n<" %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  f('<%= j(a)           %>') // === '\\n&lt;'
  f('<%= j(a).html_safe %>') // === '\\n<'
<% end %>
```

**to_json + html_safe**

Works because JSON is [almost a subset of Javascript object literal notation](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Works not only on hash objects, but also on strings, arrays and integers which are
converted to JSON fragments of the corresponding data type.

```
<% data = { key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2' } %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var data = <%= data.to_json.html_safe %>
  f(data.key1) \\ === 'val1'
  f(data.key2) \\ === 'val2'
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks - if they're not duplicates then they deserve individual answers

Comment: data- attributes is simple and easy. Thank you