# How to render action.js.coffee.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting a "missing template" error message when rendering an action with a js.coffee.erb extension.  If I rename it to js.coffee or js.erb, I can get the controller to recognize the file, but I lose the pre-processor.

It looks like previous versions did not require the .erb to process ERB, but now it is required and the controller doesn't recognize the template.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504092/erb-in-coffee-script-with-rails-3-1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Rails is going to support rendering coffee script from an action:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2391