# Updating the values of rails instance-variables in a view after updating them in the controller using an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a partial that renders on my home page, and it displays fields from an instance variable, @matchup (e.g. @matchup.num_votes). When the matchup is clicked, a jQuery event-handler makes an AJAX request to the server that updates the value of fields on @matchup, and then updates the value of @matchup by pulling a Matchup object at random.

How can I make these changes (the new value of @matchup) reflect in the view without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Could you break down your desired behaviour into steps? Finding it difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

the you can update the HTML of the object through `*.js.erb`. You need the ID of DOM element which inner HTML you want to update. If the ID of the DOM is "match_up":

```
$("#match_up").html('<%= escape_javascript(name of partial file which contain new html)) %>');
```

Comment: Thanks, can I use .js.erb with coffeescript? .js.coffee.erb?

Comment: you will got your answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504092/erb-in-coffee-script-with-rails-3-1)