# Displaying object address with CoffeeScript or jQuery in Rails Form with grouped_collection_select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have a Rails 3.2.20 app which I have a form setup that selects a facility which has a `facility_name` and `facility_address` field in the facility model.  This is a relationship between the `Call` and `Facility` model to allow facilities to be assigned to calls.

Currently I'm able to select a facility and assign it no problem by selecting the name from a dropdown/search using `select2`.  But what I want to be able to do is when selecting the facility have a small div display next to it with the `facility_address` for the specific `facility.id`.  So when I select 24 hour emergency room, a small div will show the address for the facility.

I'm unsure as to how to do this with jQuery or CoffeeScript as I'm a bit rusty.  Attached is a screenshot of what my form looks like.  Below is what I have so far to handle the jQuery, but I need to figure out a way to pass a data attribute to `grouped_collection_select` so I can get the `address` data field to display with jQuery.  Whenever I select a facility the div will pop out with "undefined"

I'm not sure if I can even pass a data attribute like `data: {address: :facility_address}`.  Trying this yields errors.  There's go to be some way to do this.  Or perhaps restructuring it to a `select` form helper and use `group_options_for_select`

[image]

I'm doing searches on how to display data from a form field using jQuery or CoffeeScript but so far I haven't found anything specific.

If you need code examples of my form or more data about my models relationships, please let me know.  But basically I just need to display a facility address once the facility.id is selected in the form.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :transfer_from_id, Region.order(:area), :active_facilities, :area, :id, :facility_name, {include_blank: true}, class: 'select' %><div id ="transfer-from-address"></div>
```

**region.rb**

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :area
  has_many :calls
  has_many :facilities

  def active_facilities 
    self.facilities.active
  end
end
```

**calls.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  facilities = $('#call_transfer_from_id').html()

  update_facilities = ->
    region = $('#call_region_id :selected').text()
    options = $(facilities).filter("optgroup[label=#{region}]").html()

    if options
      # Set the options and include a blank option at the top
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').html("<option value=''></option>" + options)
      # Ensure that the blank option is selected
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').attr("selected", "selected")
    else
      $('#call_transfer_from_id').empty()

  $('#call_region_id').change ->
    update_facilities()

  update_facilities()

  jQuery ->
  $("#call_transfer_from_id").on "change", (e) ->
    selected = $("#call_transfer_from_id option:selected")
    $("#transfer-from-address").html("""
    <h3>#{selected.data("address")}</h3>
    """)
```

Comment: how did you get those fancy selects ?

Comment: Using the `select2` gem.  It's really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but none using the default `grouped_collection_select`. That method takes both an `option_key_method` and an `option_value_method`, but these are intended as basic getters on the collection member to fill in the content of the option tag, not replace the option tag in entirety. I see three primary options

## create your own select tag builder

Write your own select builder that uses `content_tag` to build your own option tag inside the select, something similar to:

```
content_tag(:option, facility.name, value: facility.id, data: {address: facility.address})
```

#### [EDIT] - adding a simple select builder as the OP asked.

Assuming a helper as defined.

```
  def select_with_data_attributes(addys)
    content_tag(:select, {}) do
      raw addys.map {|a| content_tag(:option, value: a[1], data: {address: a[0]}) { a[0] } }.join
    end
  end
```

you could render this in your view with:

```
<%= select_with_data_attributes(@addresses.map{|a| [a.address, a.id]}) %>
```

This will construct html that looks like:

```
<select>
  <option data-address="123 elm st" value="1">123 elm st</option>
  <option data-address="345 elm st" value="2">345 elm st</option>
</select>
```

I pretty much disagree with this approach though, because you'll end up working against form builder libraries like simple_form and the built in helpers for rails as well.

## do an ajax request for the address

This would be a better choice (especially if its a really long list) since it feels kinda ugly to be pushing this stuff into the option element, and it can take a long time to render that much html. You could make a full `GET` request to a server endpoint.

```
$.get("/facilities/#{selectedOption}/address").done(...etc)
```

Dynamically populating your selects via server requests as the user chooses options is the only advisable method once you get a fair number of facilities and locations, so this direction would be the biggest refactor from your current code, but potentially the best long term solution.

## Render the data in the view to support your form

This would be my choice for small amounts of dynamic data. The idea would be to render a custom script tag with the addresses serialized into a data structure.

Based on the sample html from the api docs here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

I put together a little jsbin showing a rough approach.

http://jsbin.com/kuwivuxipu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

From that jsbin, the important bits below:

```
update_facilities = (e)->
    selectedValue = $(e.currentTarget).val()
    continent = data[selectedValue]
    $('#address').text(continent)

$('select').on 'change', update_facilities
```

html in the head

```
  <script> 
    // I'm just making up a data structure here
    // and obviously scoping this poorly, but you get the idea
    window.data = {
     1: 'Africa', 
     2: 'Europe', 
     3: 'Africa', 
     7: 'Europe'
    }
  </script>
```

You can just render this data into your view by doing something like `@facilities.to_json` and providing a proper serializer (advisable) to create the data you need, or potentially by creating a facilities helper (maybe easier) that builds the data for you:

```
def facilities_json
  # could also use Enumerable#inject instead of each_with_object
  data = @facilities.each_with_object({}) do |item, memo|
    memo[item.id] = memo.address
  end
  data.to_json
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll have to wrap my head around this for a bit.  Do you mind if I ask you follow up questions on this?  There's quite a few ways to do this.  I'm really trying to keep my grouped menu ergo why I use the `grouped_collection_select`.  It'd be so much nicer if I could just pass a data attribute from within that.

Comment: sure. I don't think you can though. like I said, you'd have to create your own select builder with lower level api tools available in rails, like `content_tag`.

Comment: Would you mind presenting an example of a `select` tag that I could use in my form that would allow me to use the data attributes?  I figured it should be a `f.select` helper with `options_from_collection_for_select` in there but having a hard time with all of my grouped options making it work.  Thanks in advance! :) Cheers!

Comment: nope, you won't be able to use it like that. you'll have to do something like `content_tag(:select) do ; content_tag(:option) ; end` and build up those content tags inside a helper.

Comment: added an example select tag builder.

Comment: Thanks for the example select tag build.  I'm working on implementing this and seeing how it goes.  It just seems like a lot of work to implement something simple.  Or maybe I'm just overthinking it.  Guess Rails can't do everything.

Comment: yep, that's why I advised the other two options for you  :)

Comment: Dually noted, I'll look into the other two options.  They seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I did to fix it was go to this site http://coffeescript.org/. And compile my Coffescript to Javascript and then include a script tag in the view page I needed it and place my Complied Coffescript to Javascript in there and it worked.

Additionally there is a Railscast partially on this issue #88 Dynamic Select Menus (revised) - RailsCasts. (and if you don't have an account you can view pro episodes for free on youtube! sorry Ryan Bates)

Comment: Thanks, I'm a Railscast member, also a fan of GoRails.  My problem is really not with CoffeeScript to JS compilation but more so trying to figure out how to pass a data attribute in `grouped_collection_select` that my jQuery/Coffee can read.

Comment: Oh I think you need a Select tag and then pass in options_from_collection_for_select with the arguments of your Table's option values

Comment: I think you're right about the select tag. But I'm trying to figure out how to pass all of my arguments into `options_from_collection_for_select`.  I'm having syntax errors and also need to figure out how to pass in a data attribute so jQuery will render it.

Answer (score -1):

as js.erb :

```
faciltiy_address = { <%= Facility.all.map { |e| "'#{e.id}': '#{e.address}'" }.join(', ') %> }

$('your_select').change(function() { $('your_address_wrapper').html(facility_address[$(this).val()])
)}
```

**EDIT :**

as js.coffee

```
$ ->
  faciltiy_address = { <%= Facility.all.map { |e| "#{e.id}: '#{e.address}'" }.join(', ') %> }
  $('#facility_transfer_from_id').change -> 
    $('#transfer-from-address').html(facility_address[parseInt($(this).val())])
```

Notes :

-not sure of the css ids

-coffee views will parse erb as https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237332/1801147

-depends on the number of facilities, you would prefer an ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  I'm not sure where I would drop this in. My form is `_form.html.erb` would this need to be another file?  Or is there anyway this can be rewritten to be included in a coffeescript or .js file in assets?

Comment: you can drop this either in inline js at the end of your form or in e separate forms.js.erb to include in your application.js

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try it and see if it works.  I'm still a bit unsure as to how this works but I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried creating a `_form.js.erb` and pasting the code you supplied.  My element to change is `call_transfer_from_id` and I created an empty div with an ID of `transfer_address`.  When I go to change the Facility name, nothing happens and there's no output in the console in chrome when I inspect the element.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: you have to bind the change event to the right element use jquery css's $('#model-name_attribute') with rails forms conventions

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer.  I'm trying to get this working in my js.coffee file and I'm getting `Unexpected 'COMPARE'` as an exception on the following line: ` faciltiy_address = { <%= Facility.all.map { |e| "#{e.id}: '#{e.address}'" }.join(', ') %> }`  Any idea why?