# How to use ruby code in coffeescript jquery when we want to select an object with dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

Well, I know that's a common question and found a lot of advice how to do it but it doesn't work for me and I can't understand what's the matter.

**index.html.slim**

```
- books.each do |book|
  .row class = "review_form" id = book.id
    .panel
      == render 'reviews/form', review: review, book: book
```

**book.js.coffee**

```
$('.row.review_form').hide()
  $('#new_review_button').on "click", ->
    $('.row.review_form#<%= book.id %>').show()
    $('#new_review_button').hide()
  $('#cancel_review').on "click", ->
    $(".row.review_form#<%= book.id %>").hide()
    $('#new_review_button').show()
```

According to instructions if you want to use ruby code in javascript you should use *<%= ruby code %>* as i'm doing here         *$('.row.review_form#<%= book.id %>').show()* but nothing happens. It seems like when i write *<%=* in brackets it changes into one string and js doesn't understand it's a selector with ruby code. What am I doing wrong? Please, help, I'm totally confused! ><

Comment: What exactly is the error here?

Comment: @Sergio No error, just nothing happens. If I open console and see js there is just $(".row.review_form#<%= book.id %>").hide(); 
not $(".row.review_form#1").hide(); for instance. And rubymine highlights this line as if it was just a string but not selector when i start writing <%=

Comment: Where do you render your coffee file then? Keep in mind that `book` exists only within that `each` block.

Comment: But isn't Ruby server-side and Coffeescript (javascript) client-side? How could these two worlds possibly interact?

Comment: I think you need double quotes and `#{}`. `$(".row.review_form##{book.id}").show()`. [source](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/strings/interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you dont have a rails object in your coffee script file. You can rename your file to `book.js.coffee.erb` to execute `<%= %># erb tags`. Otherwise it will be considered as a string only. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504092/erb-in-coffee-script-with-rails-3-1)  answer for more details. Hope it works :-)