# URL of images in JavaScript code using Rails 3.1 asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, image, asset-pipeline, rails-3.1

In CSS files, you can get the proper name of an image asset (with the fingerprint) by using:

```
background-image: url(image-url("rails.png"))
```

but how do you do the same from a JavaScript file?

Comment: Can you give an example usage of this in CSS and HTML?

Comment: you should use `background-image: image-url("rails.png")`. not relevant to this question though...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I see you are using the sass helper method.

In standard (non Sass) CSS you do something like this:

`.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }`

The CSS file will need to have erb added to the extensions:

`file_name.css.erb`

For javascript the same rules apply:

`file_name.js.erb`

and in the file:

`var image_path = '<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>'`

The Rails [asset pipeline guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) is an excellent source of information about how to use these features.

Comment: The answer, in short is, use erb.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4, instead of using a `js.erb` view I recommend that you stick to the asset pipeline, and pass the URL to it with a variable instead using gon or some other technique discussed at: [Ruby on Rails - Send JavaScript variable from controller to external Javascript asset file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721880/ruby-on-rails-send-javascript-variable-from-controller-to-external-javascript)

With `gon`:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <%= include_gon %>
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter { gon.path = asset_path 'image.png' }
```

app/assets/javascripts/file.js.coffee:

```
alert gon.path
```

This method is faster because file is precompiled only once at startup, gets served by the server instead of through Rails, and on the same HTTP request as the rest of the Js.