# How to load precompiled images using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, precompile

In my rails application I changed navbar icons using jquery, When the images are precompiled the image name is like 'nav1_completed-0d81e4b2c254459e456870960fa480c2.png', How do I load this image using jquery?

```
$('#nav1').find('img').attr('src', "/assets/nav1_completed.png");
```

When I load the above function it doesn't load image since the names are different, how to load images using jquery?

Comment: Why couldn't you split the string using hyphen ('-'), if it exists in all the precompiled images?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381041/url-of-images-in-javascript-code-using-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below to check if your image name starts with `nav1`

```
$('#nav1').find("img[name^='nav1']").attr('src', "/assets/nav1_completed.png");
```