# How to use rails code / pass variables to a .coffee javascript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

What would be the best way to pass values inside a .coffee script? Renaming the file to .erb breaks my app so what are the alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: access controller instance variable in CoffeeScript or JavaScript asset file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513912/rails-access-controller-instance-variable-in-coffeescript-or-javascript-asset-f)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

checkout this rails guide. this section : [2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb)
You can use rails code in .coffee-script file. It's built-in feature.

**2nd Edit___**

If the file is in assets pipeline then you need to add .erb extension at end of coffee file so that the rails tag works otherwise there is no need to add .erb extension if you moves the file in views folder rails tag works there.

Comment: I think that the document you've linked to states that you need to change extension from .coffee to .coffee.erb

Answer (score 3):

You can either (1) move the file into your app/views directory (so it won't be in the asset pipeline), or (2) pass the information via query string.

(1) app/views/users/script.js.coffee.erb

```
var username = <%= @user.name %>
```

(2) I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/885036) function

```
<%= link_to "User", user_path(@user, :username => @user.name) %>
...
var username = getParameterByName('username')
```

Untested but this is the general idea.