# Populate javascript array from database values in ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Consider following is my database table:

```
+-----------------------+
| Title     |   Date    |
+-----------------------+
| Meeting   | 03/28/2013|
| Lunch     | 03/09/2013|
+-----------------------+
```

Following is my javascript array whose values i am trying to populate as per my database values. I did it very easily with PHP but i am not able to do it with ruby kindly let me know how can I do so in ruby on rails?

Thanks,

```
var events = [ 
// Ruby FOR LOOP
    { Title: "% VALUE SHOULD COME HERE FROM DATABASE %", Date: new Date("% VALUE SHOULD COME HERE FROM DATABASE %") }
// END FOR LOOP
             ];
```

];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database table is named events - The short answer is

```
Event.all.to_json
```

But you'll probably want to refine the result

```
events = Event.all.map do |event|
  { Title: event.title, Date: event.event_date }
end

events.to_json
```

NOTE: change `all` to use the appropriate `where` filters for your use case

Use `I18n.localize` to format your date (if needed, default should be YYYY-MM-DD, which you probably want for json data) - see http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/42-use-i18n-localize-for-date-time-formating

Comment: @iAmRubuuu i cant join due to my less reputation

Comment: you meant `var events = (rest of your answered codes)` shouldn't i have to inculde tags in it for ruby code differentiation?

Comment: so can i pass the events variable as it it to my javascript function? I guess your codes explains how to create array in ruby as per database values , i m trying to populate avascript array from DB values in ruby

Comment: wait does `events.to_json` transform the whole ruby array in javascript array `events` ?

Comment: yes that is generating a json array from data in db that you could consume in javascript - take a look at this for a few other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513912/rails-access-controller-instance-variable-in-coffeescript-or-javascript-asset-f/8515242#8515242