# Converting Rails datetime to Javascript Date in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime

There has been some discussion of how it is possible to convert a Rails UTC DateTime into a Javascript date value, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date). However, I am seeing errors when I try to go a step further and make that DateTime dynamic.

In the end, I am trying to make a JS countdown timer that will show the remaining seconds between `Time.now` (Rails) and a set UTC time called `game_start`. I am [using this scrappy method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162197/rails-pass-data-to-javascript) for passing a Rails object (like a DateTime from a table) into Javascript.

So currently, I am doing the following:

```
 // This is the scrappy way I am storing a temp value for DateTime
 <%= content_tag :div, class: "temp_information", data: {temp: @tempquiz} do %>
    <% end %>

 <div id="timer"></div>

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var dt = $('.temp_information').data('temp');
     alert(dt);
   });
```

This returns a UTC string as an alert, like `2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00`. So I am successfully passing that Rails data into JS. T

he issue is when I try to combine it with some Javascript, like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('.temp_information').data('temp');
    var dt = new Date (<%= data.ToJavaScriptMilliseconds() %>);
    alert(dt);
    });
```

If I am going to make a timer that counts down, I am going to need to capture the `game_start` time (temp is doing that) and convert it to JS Milliseconds (that is breaking). However, when I do that (code is [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date)), I get this error:

```
   undefined local variable or method `data'
```

I don't get it at all, since I am defining `data` in the line before within the `$(document).ready` as the UTC string we saw in the alert. If it knows what `data` is and can return the alert in the first instance, how is it unable to produce it in the second instance?

Comment: You are mixing javascript and ruby code. `data` is a JS-Variable but you are trying to use it as a Ruby Variable in the `<%= data ...%>` block.

Comment: @MartinSchneider Dang it. I thought that was weird. I saw another example online that did it, and it didn't make a lot of sense to me why it would not require the controller if it was in the <script> tags.

Comment: Ok, getting closer. So I remove the Ruby variable and try something like: `var dt = new Date (data);` but it returns "Invalid Date." Is there still some conversion that has to be done before I can use `Date` in JS?

Answer (score 3):

Passing data to a tag in ruby, will render a data attribute on the html tag. The tag is `<div> class='temp_information' data-temp='2016-02-18 09:38:41 +0100' </div>` in the above case.

**UPDATE**: however this is a format which can't be parsed by all browsers. The most reliable method is to convert the time to a unix timestamp.

Also the [ISO 8601](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_date_parse_iso_8601) format should be supported by all browsers now. This format is used by [GitHub Api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits) for example.

The ruby `Time` object can be converted to javascript `date` like this

#### ruby

```
Time.at(1644394891).to_i
=> 1644394891

require 'time'
Time.at(1644394891).utc.iso8601
=> "2022-02-09T08:21:31Z"
```

#### javascript

```
new Date(1644394891 * 1000)
=> Wed Feb 09 2022 09:21:31 GMT+0100 (CET)

new Date("2022-02-09T08:21:31Z")
=> Wed Feb 09 2022 09:21:31 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

So for your code it's

```
new Date($('.temp_information').data('temp'));
```

you have to call `@tempquiz.utc.iso8601` before rendering

Comment: Good catch. I think we're close, but it's being strange. So if I convert the line to: `new Date ($('.temp_information').data('temp'));`, it shows an alert for `Invalid Date.` If I remove the `new Date` though and make it `var temp = $('.temp_information').data('temp');`, the alert will show the UTC string, like `2016-02-18T23:07:00.000-08:00`. Do I need an intermediary step to convert the UTC string to milliseconds before I can add it to `new Date` maybe?

Comment: Forgot to tag you @dre-hh. If you have any feedback on how to work with that, I think this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Does this work? `new Date("2016-02-18 09:38:41 +0100")` returns "Invalid date" for me.

Comment: On chrome its returns a valid date. Where are you running this?

Comment: https://techtalkbook.com/javascripts-new-date-does-not-work-on-ie-and-safari/

Turns out this format is not supported accoss all browsers

Comment: @AdamBohannon i have updated the answer to use a utc iso8601 string