# Injecting variable values into javascript and HAML in RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following function for using ZenDesk.  I'd like to inject my current_user details into the form as follows. (this is my from html.haml template).  However I cannot figure out how to make this work.

```
:javascript
    if (typeof(Zenbox) !== "undefined") {
      Zenbox.init({
        dropboxID:   "xxxxx",
        url:         "xxxxx.zendesk.com",
        tabID:       "support",
        tabColor:    "black",
        tabPosition: "Left",
        requester_name:  =current_user ? "#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}" : "" ,
        requester_email: =current_user ? "#{current_user.email}" : "" ,
        hide_tab: true
        });
    }
```

In short, how does one inject rails variables into a :javascript element in haml.

Comment: The answers will be the same without HAML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464966/passing-ruby-variables-to-javascript-function-in-rails-view

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This should work ie. put all inline ruby inside of `#{}`:

```
requester_name:  "#{current_user.first_name + ' ' + current_user.last_name if current_user}",
requester_email: "#{current_user.email if current_user}",
```

Comment: And how about the reverse direction? i.e.

    :javascript
      #{raw some_helper(ARGUMENTS FROM JS HERE)}

Comment: Javascript runs in a browser and ruby on server so you can't do it like that.

Answer (score 35):

Direct `#{}` works for simple strings, but is not the most scalable / safe solution in general.

For example, the literal backslash in Ruby would cause you problems in Javascript where it will be interpreted as a newline character:

```
- a = "\\n"
:javascript
  '#{ a }' !== "\\n"
```

From [this awesome Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast), the following techniques can be used:

**escape_javascript**

Alias: `j`.

Works only on strings.

Escapes characters that can have special meanings in Javascript strings,
like backslash escapes, into a format suitable to put inside Javascript string literal quotes.

Maintain `html_safe` status of input,
so needs `html_safe` otherwise special HTML chars like `<` would get escaped into `&lt;`.

```
- a = "\\n<"
:javascript
  '#{ j(a)           }' === '\\n&lt;'
  '#{ j(a).html_safe }' === '\\n<'
```

**to_json + html_safe**

Works because JSON is [almost a subset of Javascript object literal notation](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Works on any hash object, including strings, arrays and integers which are
converted to JSON fragments of the corresponding data type.

```
- data = { key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2' }
:javascript
  data = #{ data.to_json }
  data.key1 === 'val1'
  data.key2 === 'val2'
```

**data- attributes**

Add values to attributes, retrieve them with Javascript DOM operations.

Better with the `content_tag` helper:

```
= content_tag 'div', '', id: 'data', data: {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'}
:javascript
  $('#data').data('key1') === 'val1'
  $('#data').data('key2') === 'val2'
```

**gon**

Library specialized for the job: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Probably the most robust solution.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'gon'
```

Controller:

```
gon.key1 = 'val1'
gon.key2 = 'val2'
```

Layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <%= include_gon %>
```

View:

```
:javascript
  gon.key1 === 'val1'
  gon.key2 === 'val2'
```

Comment: Downvoters please explain so I can improve info. I never retaliate. Thanks.