# passing ruby variables to javascript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of medicines and a list of vaccinations that I am extracting from tables medicines and vaccinations respectively. The list of medicines is of the format medicine_name and so is the list of vaccinations. I store both of these in vars using this piece of code.

```
var injections=<%=@injections%>;
var medicines=<%=@medicines%>;
```

In my view I have select tags for medicines and injections but when I try to append these vars to the respective tags using the following code. I don't get any results please help

```
$('.addmedicines').click(function()
   $('.medicines').append(medicines);


});
$('.addinjections').click(function(){
   $('.injections').append(injections);
});
```

Here .injections is the class assigned to select tag for vaccinations. .medicines is the class assigned to select tag for medicines. And .addmedicines and .addinjections are html buttons.

EDITED:

When I try to display both injections and medicines in javascript they display like this:

Medicines:

```
<option>Med1</option><option>Med2</option><option>Med3</option><option>Med4</option>
```

Injections:

```
<option>i1</option><option>i2</option><option>i3</option><option>i4</option>
```

Comment: are you trying to add options to those select tags upon clicking of `.addmedicines` and `.addinjections` ?

Comment: Can you post the select tag markup here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing ruby variables to javascript function in rails view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464966/passing-ruby-variables-to-javascript-function-in-rails-view)

Answer (score 23):

```
var injections= '<%=@injections%>';
var medicines='<%=@medicines%>';
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Rails helper [array_or_string_for_javascript](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/array_or_string_for_javascript), or just simply call `to_json`:

```
var injections = <%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@injections) %>;
var medicines = <%= array_or_string_for_javascript(@medicines) %>;

// OR

var injections = <%= @injections.to_json %>;
var medicines = <%= @medicines.to_json %>;
```

Comment: `array_or_string_for_javascript` was deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a `{` after the first function

Should be:

```
$('.addmedicines').click(function(){  // <-- right here :)
   $('.medicines').append(medicines);


});
$('.addinjections').click(function(){
   $('.injections').append(injections);
});
```

What you have:

```
$('.addmedicines').click(function()   // <-- right here :)
   $('.medicines').append(medicines);


});
$('.addinjections').click(function(){
   $('.injections').append(injections);
});
```